# Нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: пунктуация

"Легкие деньги" пишется в кавычках или нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выражение ЛЁГКИЕ ДЕНЬГИ уже вошло в словари (Финансовый, словарь бизнес-терминов, русско-немецкий словарь и др.), поэтому не является выражением, имеющим необычное значение. А если слово (или выражение) зафиксировано в словарях, то кавычки чаще всего не ставятся.